# Why is full name used for DN in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

[Rewriting my question based on comments]

My DN in Active Directory is "CN=Jesse Barnum,cn=users,dc=360works,dc=com".

I'm writing a web application which attempts to bind to the LDAP server, using the username and password of the active user. When doing the bind, I use the format "CN=$loginName$,cn=users,dc=360works,dc=com". Therefore, my users need to type in their full name (ie. 'Jesse Barnum'), rather than their shorter UID ('jbarnum').

Since users logging in typically expect to type a short name (like 'jbarnum', rather than 'Jesse Barnum'), I'd like for my DN to use my short name, like this: "CN=jbarnum,cn=users,dc=360works,dc=com". Doesn't it seem like that should be the default behavior (Windows Server 2012)?

So my question is: Can I change how the DN is constructed in Active Directory to use the short name instead of the full name?

Comment: That's not a CN, it's a DN (Distinguished Name). Only the first part is a CN.

Comment: OK, sorry for the terminology mixup. The question still stands - shouldn't the distinguished name be based on the short name, rather than the full display name?

Comment: Why should it? The DN has to be unique inside the LDAP. That's the only requirement. Why would you want your DN to contain your short name (being the UID)? For Login you normaly don't have to fill in the DN but simply your CN or your UID.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand your own question. What you're really asking is why does the *CN part of the DN* consist of firstName plus surname when you want it to be something else. You're asking about the CN but you're providing the full DN.

Comment: Thank you EJP and heiglandreas - I edited my question based on your comments.

Answer (score 4):

You can change that behaviour but why should you? As you want to create a login there are much more elegant and more flexible solutions available.

When creating an LDAP based login I'm always doing the following:

- bind to the server with a special account that can search the LDAP. Often that can also be done with a so called "anonymous bind".
- search the LDAP for the given username in any attribute you like. A filter of `(|(uid=username)(mail=username)(cn=username))` would allow your user to either use the uid, mail or cn to log in.
- get the dn from the retrieved result and use that DN  whic should be the DN of the users record) for a second bind - this time with the provided Password

That way the DN is completely irrellevant for your login as i is retrieved using the provided information based on attributes.

For an example in PHP have a look at https://gist.github.com/heiglandreas/5689592

Comment: Completely agree! I just did a related blog post, there is a example on how to search users based on sAMAccountName (or any other attribute) using the Apache LDAP API: http://blog.techutils.space/2016/02/changing-samba4-aws-simple-ad-user.html

Answer (score 1):

The CN can be based on anything, really. It comes down to how you provision your users in the directory. If you use the out-of-box AD Users and Computers or AD Administrative Center tools to create users, they default to the full name format. You can change the CN after the fact, or if you are using something programmatic to create users, then you can create them however you like initially.